# "a href" Tag with WatiN

Tags: tags, watin, href

How can I click on the link defined by the tag "a href="#" onclick="pesqResp();"> Search " using WatiN?

Form verifies that the ID exists, if yes shows the form again with the employee's name, if not shows form again with error message

Comment: Can you show what you are trying?

Comment: I think this would work: browser.Link(Find.By("onclick", "pesqResp();")).Click();

Answer (score 0):

You can use Class or Id to find the link the command to click on link is:

```
browser.Eval("$('.ClassNameHere').click();");
```

Comment: tks boys, the command: browser.Link(Find.By("onclick", "pesqResp();")).Click(); is OK

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
browser.Link(link => link.Text == "Search").Click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Link(link => link.Text == "Search").Click(); this works saved lot of time!